# How can I get unique branch of xmltype as varchar?

Tags: sql, xml, database, oracle

Oracle 11g2.
For example:

```
select XMLType( 
'<main>
  <article> 
    <title>1.txt</title>
      <type>market</type>
      <author>
        <name>J. Smith</name>   
        <age>32</age>
      </author>
  </article>
  <comment>For information</comment>
</main>').getStringVal() from dual;
```

Could you help me modify this select statement ?
I'd like to get **varchar** output as :

```
<title>1.txt</title>
<type>market</type>
<author>
  <name>J. Smith</name>   
  <age>32</age>
</author>
```

unfortunately, using extract('/main/article') as:

```
select XMLType( 
'<main>
  <article> 
    <title>1.txt</title>
      <type>market</type>
      <author>
        <name>J. Smith</name>   
        <age>32</age>
      </author>
  </article>
  <comment>For information</comment>
</main>').extract('/main/article').getStringVal() from dual;
```

lose format of the text (all output in one row).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to get the nodes without a root node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Boneist shows you can use [`xmlserialize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions252.htm) for the formatting, but as you only seem to have a single article node in your document you can still use your `extract()`:

```
select xmlserialize(document XMLType( 
'<main>
  <article> 
    <title>1.txt</title>
      <type>market</type>
      <author>
        <name>J. Smith</name>   
        <age>32</age>
      </author>
  </article>
  <comment>For information</comment>
</main>').extract('/main/article')
  as varchar2(200) indent) as article
from dual;
```

Or you can use an XMLQuery:

```
select xmlserialize(document xmlquery('/main/article'
  passing XMLType( 
'<main>
  <article> 
    <title>1.txt</title>
      <type>market</type>
      <author>
        <name>J. Smith</name>   
        <age>32</age>
      </author>
  </article>
  <comment>For information</comment>
</main>')
  returning content)
  as varchar2(200) indent) as article
from dual;

ARTICLE                                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<article>                                                                       
  <title>1.txt</title>                                                          
  <type>market</type>                                                           
  <author>                                                                      
    <name>J. Smith</name>                                                       
    <age>32</age>                                                               
  </author>                                                                     
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (well, including the article node) via XMLTABLE and XMLSERIALISE to do the pretty printing, e.g.:

**Query**

```
with sample_data as (select XMLType( 
'<main>
  <article> 
    <title>1.txt</title>
      <type>market</type>
      <author>
        <name>J. Smith</name>   
        <age>32</age>
      </author>
  </article>
  <comment>For information</comment>
</main>') xdata from dual)
select xmlserialize(document x.col1 as varchar2(4000) indent size = 2)
from   sample_data sd
       cross join xmltable('/main/article'
                           passing sd.xdata
                           columns col1 xmltype path '.') x;
```

**Result**

```
<article>
  <title>1.txt</title>
  <type>market</type>
  <author>
    <name>J. Smith</name>
    <age>32</age>
  </author>
</article>
```